# SharePoint list - provided @odata.nextLink results in Error 500

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

It seems there's an issue happening (at least within my tenant) when paging results from SharePoint Online lists; the URL provided in `@odata.nextLink` doesn't work, resulting in `Error 500 (generalException)`.

I'm using a following query:

```
/beta/sites/[site URL],[site ID]/lists/[list ID]/items?expand=fields
```

The first page of results comes in correctly, and the `@odata.nextLink` property contains a following URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/[site URL],[site ID]/lists/[list ID]/items?expand=fields&$skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d205
```

Unfortunately, using it results in:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "f7e33c22-15b5-4aac-b928-31c1a2bf04ae",
            "date": "2018-01-11T09:48:57"
        }
    }
}
```

- This happens using both the `/beta` and `/v1.0` endpoint.
- Tested on multiple lists and sites within my tenant.
- Tested without `?expand=fields`
- It was working perfectly before last Thursday (Jan. 11th).

The customer service for O365 is unable to help, pointing me to MSDN forums.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention Jakub. You found a regression that slipped through our testing - thankfully there was a quick solution so you should no longer reproduce the issue.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for a quick fix! It's all working again :-)

Comment: Looks like this issue has returned as of 2019-08-22